# server returning 302 moved on create in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, http-status-code-302

I've got a Backbone.js/Rails app and I'm trying to create a new object through Backbone `model.save()`.

The server is returning a `302 moved`, but checking the rails controller, the create object exists, and I can navigate to the index, so the routes are properly in place.

I've tried replacing the backbone.js with a regular jquery .ajax function, and both return the `302`, as I originally thought the error was in backbone, but I think this is showing that the error is actually in rails.

The request payload/parameters is pretty simple

```
{"user_id":130,"message_text":"does this go 302","authenticity_token":"GxN8nPf5YwS2j2HhWZxWiKej3Y72Vb5IQZ98u5Nl2gs="}
```

The backbone save method is

```
          var user_message = new Myapp.Models.UserMessage({
                user_id: user.id,
                message_text: $('input[name="message"]',this.el).val()
          });

         user_message.save({
                success: function(response) {
                new Message({message: response.message});
            },
                error: function() {
                new Error({ message: "adding message" });
            }
       });
```

Comment: a "302" response has nothing to do with backbone, as you've noted. you should post the rails code from the controller, and any pertinent configuration of routes that would do a "redirect" from the controller. it looks like you have authorization / authentication code that is causing this.

Comment: dear god Derick!! How on earth did you figure out it was an authorization error. I've been looking at this for 10 hours and didn't figure that out. You're right. Please post this as the answer and I'll give you the WIN!

Comment: :) glad I could help. It was the combination of the 302 response and the authenticity_token in the response that made me think of authorization/authentication.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A "302" response has nothing to do with backbone, as you've noted. It looks like you have authorization / authentication code that is causing this.